# java/scala: Regex for skipping odd number of backslash while splitting a String?

Tags: java, regex, scala

Here is my requirement:

```
Input1: adasd|adsasd\|adsadsadad|asdsad
output1: Array(adasd,adsasd\|adsadsadad,asdsad)

Input2: adasd|adsasd\\|adsadsadad|asdsad
output2: Array(adasd,adsasd\\,adsadsadad,asdsad)

Input3: adasd|adsasd\\\|adsadsadad|asdsad
output3: Array(adasd,adsasd\\\|adsadsadad,asdsad)
```

I was using this code:

```
val delimiter =Pattern.quote("|")
val esc = "\\"
val regex = "(?<!" + Pattern.quote(esc) + ")" + delimiter
```

But this is not working fine with all the cases.

What will be the best solution to deal with this?

Comment: Does this work? https://regex101.com/r/H4oqsk/1

Comment: Since you'd also want to process the ``\``-escapes, I'd suggest you parse the text instead of using a regex. If you don't want to write your own, use a customizable CSV parser.

Comment: What cases does it **not** work for? What is the incorrect result?

Comment: @jwvh for Input2 this will return Array(adasd,adsasd\\|adsadsadad,asdsad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting, use this regex for a match:

```
(?<=[|]|^)[^|\\]*(?:\\.[^|\\]*)*
```

[Java Code Demo](https://ideone.com/uMs5ab)

**Java code:**

```
final String[] input = {"adasd|adsasd\\|adsadsadad|asdsad",
        "adasd|adsasd\\\\|adsadsadad|asdsad",
        "adasd|adsasd\\\\\\|adsadsadad|asdsad"};

final String regex = "(?<=[|]|^)[^|\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^|\\\\]*)*";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher;

for (String string: input) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    System.out.println("\n*** Input: " + string);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
*** Input: adasd|adsasd\|adsadsadad|asdsad
adasd
adsasd\|adsadsadad
asdsad

*** Input: adasd|adsasd\\|adsadsadad|asdsad
adasd
adsasd\\
adsadsadad
asdsad

*** Input: adasd|adsasd\\\|adsadsadad|asdsad
adasd
adsasd\\\|adsadsadad
asdsad
```

Comment: Nope, with this input  adasd |adsasd\\|adsadsadad |asdsad,
group content what I'm getting is: adasd, adsasd\\|adsadsadad, asdsad.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a Java code demo. You can see live running code and generated output. In all 3 cases output matches with your expected output in question.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, let's take ";"(semicolon) instead of "\"(backslash) to avoid too many escape sequences here.

We can do this split with a look-behind as below:

```
    String[] input = { "adasd|zook;|adsadsadad|asdsad", "adasd|zook;;|adsadsadad|asdsad",
            "adasd|zook;;;|adsadsadad|asdsad", "blah;|blah;;;;|blah|blahblah;|blahbloooh;;|" }; 

    String regex = "(?<!;)(;;)+\\||(?<!;)\\|";
    for(String str : input) {
        System.out.println("Input : "+ str);

        System.out.println("Output: ");
        String[] astr = str.split(regex);
        for(String nres : astr)
            System.out.print(nres+", ");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Let's have a deeper look at the regex. I will split this into 2 parts:

1. Split on even occurrence of semicolon(;) followed by a pipe("|"):
   `(?<!;)(;;)+\\|`  :
   Here we make sure we match just even occurrence with (;;)+ and a look-behind to make sure we are not matching any unintended ";" before the set of even occurrences.
2. Split on pipe without a preceding semicolon:
   `(?<!;)\\|` : 
    Here we will just match lone pipe symbols and use look-behind to make sure no ";" before the "|"

[Output for the above snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpvoO.png)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This regex is removing the escape characters as well. For
Input:  adasd|zook;;|adsadsadad|asdsad 
desired output is:  adasd,zook;;,adsadsadad,asdsad